# Powershell event forwarding

Tags: events, powershell, forwarding, powershell-remoting

Sorry for bad english.

I have some troubles with powershell and events forwarding mechanism in it. Im trying to do something like this:

```
$remoteComputer = "."
$session = New-PsSession $remoteComputer

Unregister-Event CatchEvent -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Invoke-Command $session {

    ## The WMI query to detect a stopping service
    $query = @"
        SELECT *
        FROM __instancecreationevent
        WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_NtLogEvent'
        and targetinstance.eventcode = '7036'
"@
    Register-WmiEvent -Query $query "CatchEvent" -Forward
}
$null = Register-EngineEvent CatchEvent -Action { $GLOBAL:MyEvent = $event}
```

$MyEvent variable at last contains not an event information, but a system.string class data.
[alt text http://eosfor.fileave.com/powershell.png](http://eosfor.fileave.com/powershell.png)

Whats wrong with this script?

Answer (score 0):

Vasily Gusev gives me an [answer](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/scrlangru/thread/e74a0d3e-3dea-414f-afc2-c90b1d351f0d).

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM __instancecreationevent WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_NtLogEvent' AND TargetInstance.eventcode = '7036'"
Register-WmiEvent -Query $query -ComputerName client1 -Action {write-host "Service Stopped"}
```

again. sorry for bad english. just correct me if something wrong :)